# jQuery UI draggable - if element dragged

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I want when **draggable div** dragged into **droppable div**, the droppable div color get another color, then draggable div width/height get bigger and exactly fit to droppable div.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37YpH/)

for example, when you dragging red circle into the big circle, i want to chang big div color to red, and red circle get fit to big div.

for these questions i wrote down these codes:

```
    if ($(draggable).hasClass('dropped')) {
        droppable.css({
            background: 'red'
        });
        draggable.css({                    
            width: '300px',
            height: '300px'
        });
    }
```

but these doesn't works, and i dunno how to make draggable fit to droppable.

Answer (score 2):

Append `draggable` to `droppable` to make things easier.
I used `.data()` to store the element index (to remember where to put it back after being dropped).

Example:

```
$('#BigSix').droppable({
   hoverClass: 'drop-hover',
   drop: function (event, ui) {
      var _this = $(this);
      ui.draggable.addClass('dropped')
      .data('droppedin', _this)
      .data('SixIndex',ui.draggable.index());
      _this.droppable('disable')
      .append(ui.draggable)
   }
});
```

And put it back when dragged out:

```
var prevElemIndex = $(this).data('SixIndex')-1;
if(prevElemIndex==-1) {
   $("#container").prepend($(this))
}
else {
   $(".Six:eq("+prevElemIndex+")").after($(this))
}
```

You can then use CSS to style things your way:

```
#BigSix div.Six {
//(!important isnt good but i dont see another way around it)
    position: absolute !important;
    top:0 !important;
    left:0 !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
}
```

The above CSS needs you to have `position: relative` on `#BigSix` and `box-sizing:border-box` on `.Six`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/37YpH/3/

Comment: Thank you for reply, it's absolutely what i want but  one more thing, when i want to dragging out dropped div , it will jump to original position, any solution for make this softly? i mean, when we want to dragging out, it get back to default size and then revert to original position.

Comment: and another thing, it shouldn't accept another circle when one circle already dropped.any solution?